# Как заставить работать простой jquery скрипт на CMS Made Simple

Tags: jquery, html, cms, javascript

Здравствуйте. Я уже 3й день пытаюсь заставить работать простейший jquery скриптик для прокрутки страницы к заданному блоку, перепробовал уже всё! И пихал его в отдельный файл потом подключал к шаблону, потом пихал его прямо в шаблон в тегах {literal} а он не хочет работать и всё тут! 
Немного пояснений:
Вот сам скриптик

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Он у меня в отдельном js файлике. Подключаю я его к шаблону вот так

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/inf.js"></script>
```

Сам HTML код для плавного перехода до заданного блока. начало

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

И в конце странички:

```
<div class="section white" id="section2">
    <h2>Раздел №2</h2>
    <p>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>   
    </p>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Немного грубовато и много лишнего, но не суть! У меня задача заставить работать, потом будем красоту наводить.

Создаю html страничку, прописываю в ней контент любой, подключаю скрипты и о чудо там всё работает! 
Как только я пытаюсь подключить непосредственно в CMSMS в шаблон, все не работает! При этом другие jquery скрипты работают ОТЛИЧНО!

Захожу в отладчик и вижу вот такую ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

других ошибок и предупреждений нету.

И на последок, вот мой шаблон в этом шаблоне данный скрипт вставлен в теги {literal}

```
{process_pagedata}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>{sitename} | {title}</title>
{metadata}
{stylesheet}
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/jquery.feedback.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
{/literal}
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="branding">
           <div style="float: left;">
           <h1 class="logo"><a href="#" title="&lt; Magazine /&gt;">вовоааовововоао</a></h1>
                <p class="intro"><span style="color: #666666;">ваовоаваоаооа </span><br /><br>воаоваваоваоовао</p>
</div>
 <div style="width: 190px; display: inline-block;">
     <img style="padding-left: 15px;" width="180" src="/images/advokat/pic-top-right.png"/>

   </div>
<div id="branding1">
<div style="padding-left:100px;padding-top:30px">
<div id="branding2" >
<img src="images/advokat/111.png" alt="" width="40" >
</div>
<div id="branding3">
<span style="color:#666666;"><b>Контакты:</b></span>
<p><i><span style="color:#93b876;">534353</i>
<p><i><span style="color:#93b876;">53434</i></p>
<p><i><span style="color:#93b876;">248000,<span/></i></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

            {menu template='headmenu' number_of_levels='1'}
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>

    <div id="contant">
        <div class="contant_1">
            <div class="contant_1_left">
                <h2>{title}</h2> 
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>1</li>
        <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
                <p>{content}</p>
            </div>

        <div class="sideBar">
                {content block='selfinfo'}
                <div class="sideBarListBox">
                    <img src="/images/advokat/sideBarListBoxTop.png" alt="" width="240" height="10" />
                    {menu number_of_levels="2"}
                    <img src="/images/advokat/sideBarListBoxBottom.png" alt="" width="240" height="10" />
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <br class="clear" />
       </div>
    </div>
   <br />

    <div id="footer">
<div id="inf"> </div>
<div class="feedback-form">
                <div class="feedback-multi-column">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="column-full">
                            <h4><i class="icon-notebook"></i>Заказать обратный звонок</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section">
                        <form method="post" action="php/form.php" id="feedback">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="column-full2">
                                    <div id="feedback-message"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column-half">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="firstname" name="firstname"><i class="icon-user-3"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Ваше Имя">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column-half">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="lastname" name="lastname"><i class="icon-user-3"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Ваша Фамилия">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column-half">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="useremail" name="useremail"><i class="icon-envelop-opened"></i></label>
                                        <input type="email" id="useremail" name="useremail" maxlength="70" placeholder="Ваш E-mail адрес">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column-full">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="usermessage" name="usermessage"><i class="icon-bubble-10"></i></label>
                                        <textarea style="resize: none; height: 85px;" id="usermessage" name="usermessage" maxlength="200" placeholder="Опишите пожалуйста вашу проблему"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column-half">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="userphone" name="userphone"><i class="icon-phone"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="userphone" name="userphone" maxlength="70" placeholder="Ваш телефон для связи">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column-half">
                                    <button type="reset" name="clear" class="button button-mini button-red">Сбросить</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="send" name="send" class="button button-mini button-green">Отправить заявку</button>
                                    <div id="loader"></div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="column-full">
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="section white" id="section2">
    <h2>Раздел №2</h2>
    <p>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>
        Текст раздела №2<br/>   
    </p>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, мб я чего всетаки не так делаю, или еще чего, какого фига он не работает именно в CMSMS везде в других CMS и в Джумле и т.п. все работает на УРА!

Версия CMS 1.7.1

Файл jquery.feedback.js из-за него конфликты.

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#feedback input, textarea').tooltipster({
                trigger: 'custom',
                onlyOne: true,
                position: 'top'
            });
        });
    });

    jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
        $.validator.methods.equal = function(value, element, param) {
            return value == param;
        };
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#feedback").validate({   
                rules:{
                    firstname:{
                        required:true
                    },
                    lastname:{
                        required:false
                    },
                    useremail:{
                        required:true,
                        email:true
                    },
                    usermessage:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength:20
                    },
                    userphone:{
                        required:true,  
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname:{
                        required: 'Пожалуйста введите своё Имя',
                    },
                    lastname:{
                        required: 'Пожалуйста введите свою Фамилию',
                    },
                    useremail:{
                        required: 'Пожалуйста введите свой E-mail адрес',
                        email: 'Пожалуйста введите корректный E-mail адрес'
                    },
                    usermessage:{
                        required: 'Пожалуйста введите ваше сообщение'
                    },
                    userphone:{
                        required: 'Пожалуйста введите свой телефон',
                    },
                },  
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
                    $(element).tooltipster('show');
                },
                success: function (label, element) {
                    $(element).tooltipster('hide');
                },
                submitHandler:function(form) {
                    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        target:'#feedback-message',
                        beforeSubmit:function(){ 
                            $('#loader').show();
                        },
                        success:function(){ 
                            $('#loader').hide();
                            $("#feedback-message").fadeIn(500);
                            $("#feedback").each(function(){
                                this.reset();
                            });
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: а jquery точно подключается в исходной странице? отладчик не показывает, в каком именно файле и на какой строке ошибка? попробуйте обернуть код

    (function ($) {
        $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
            var $anchor = $(this);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 1000);

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    })(jQuery)

Comment: Проверьте, доступен ли файл images/advokat/Js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js прямо из страницы, также можете попробовать заменить псевдоним "$" на "jQuery", у меня как-то при смене версии jQuery на более новую перестали работать эти "доллары", помогла замена на jQuery

Comment: @MDJHD, Скрипт доступен, заменил как вы сказали, ошибка пропала, но скрипт всеравно не работает... Блин, что же CMS такая кривая то... 

@vanchester, этот способ тоже не помог... Скрипт как не работал в этом движке так и не работает... А ведь другие скрипты к форме обратной связи отлично работают... Я не знаю что делать...

Comment: @MDJHD, я как раз решение этой проблемы предложил выше - обернуть код функцией и передать в нее jQuery в качестве параметра.

@KeH192, дело не в CMS, а в подлюченных скриптах. Нужно просто выяснить, между какими скриптами конфликт идет

Comment: @vancheste, я уже отключал все jquery скрипты, оставлял только подключенным jquery, эффекта никакого. 
И как возможно узнать о конфликте если никаких ошибок или предупреждений нету.

UP! Всё починил!:) Спасибо всем за помощь. Подключил скрипт после метатегов и всё заработало))

Comment: @KeH192, ошибки при этом были? замените свой код 

    $(function () {/* код */}) 

на 

    $(document).ready(function () { /* код */})

добавьте в обработчик console.log() и посмотрите, выполняется ли он вообще при клике на ссылку

ну и еще обработчик должен возвращать false, чтобы событие клика по ссылке дальше не передавалось браузеру

Comment: @vanchester, а могли бы подробнее подсказать куда добавить console.log() ? Я только новичок в этом. 
Единственно с чем разобрался это с тем что если я убираю все скрипты и подключаю только jquery и свой скриптик то всё теперь работает! Но вот как найти этот конфликт с другими скриптами и поправить его?

UP! Путём тыка нашёл что конфликтует скрипт <script type="text/javascript" src="images/advokat/Js/jquery.feedback.js"></script> Но как исправить конфликт? Отключить его просто не вариант это форма обратной связи:( 

UUP! В свой вопрос добавил содержимое файла jquery.feedback.js

Comment: @KeH192, если есть возможность его править, то попробуйте [такой вариант][1]. Подправил его, избавившись от noConflict() и смешивания jQuery и $

PS. Пожалуйста - вводное слово, его по правилам русского языка надо запятыми обрамлять

 [1]: http://pastebin.com/vhDNNw6W

Comment: @vanchester, Спасибо большое за помощь. Я сделал немного по другому, закрыл свой скрипт в теги noConflict и всё заработало:)